# Is it safe if I use house hold scissors instead of special kitchen scissors?

Tags: equipment, water, safety

I used scissors to cut a straw for my hydroflask, then I drank out of it. Is is safe if I used plain household scissors? I rinsed the straw before I drank out of it, right after using the scissors to cut it.

Comment: Using it on a straw is better than using it on chicken or other high risk food.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that we don’t know what you did with the scissors, how well you cleaned them before and the straw after cutting.

If you used reasonably clean utensils (using the standard you would apply to regular kitchen tools like knives), there’s nothing in the material per se that would be problematic if used occasionally.

Many even professional chefs use tools that came from a hardware store rather than a cooking supply store. Once the grease from manufacturing is removed, the metal should be fine. Note that they are probably not stainless steel and thus require special care to prevent e.g. rusting, but that’s doable. I would however warn you against regularly mixing uses back and forth, especially when working with unsafe substances - even good cleaning has a small risk of leaving hazardous materials behind, a mistake is easily made and nobody wants to garnish dinner with a bit of weed killer or something alike.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wash and clean your scissors, there are no issues at all.

Kitchen scissors are just sturdier scissors.

If your scissors were just used to cut paper or cloth, there should be no problem

Comment: "Kitchen scissors are just sturdier scissors." That are usually more easily disassembled for cleaning than ordinary scissors.